# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scope in angular Js when routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, ngroute

```
var myWebsite = angular.module('myWebsite', ['ngRoute']);


myWebsite.config(['$scope', '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl : "index.html",
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl : "views/about-view.html",
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : "/home"
    });
}]);

myWebsite.controller('myWebsiteCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log("angular is initialised");
}]);

myWebsite.controller('aboutCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log("about controller is initialised");
}]);
```

This code is giving error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scope.
i am using these lines at header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.js">`enter code here`</script>

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.3/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$scope` isn't injectable inside `config` block. You can avail `$scope` dependency injected on `controller` only. Technically it is not(never) possible to inject `$scope` in `config` phase, as config block will allow to inject providers only. additionally config phase happens at time of application bootstrap(specifically before run phase).

```
myWebsite.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
```

> Note: Make sure you have `angular-route.js` referenced on page